# I got problems with setting mrgins on a container holding a background-image

Tags: css

[image]When i incrase margins left/right on a container holding a backgroun-image. the image starts to bahave weirdly. It moves to right side and is not centered anymore.

```
<section class="section--1">
        <div>
          <div class="photo--container">
            <h1 class="logo">Ableton</h1>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="text--container">
          <p class="text--main__1">
            ...
          </p>
          <p class="text--main__2">
            ...
          </p>
        </div>
      </section>
```

And here is CSS:

```
body {
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 98rem;
  height: 500rem;

.section--1 {
  max-width: 100%;
}
.section--1 div:first-child {
  margin: -12rem 8% 0 8%;
}
.photo--container {
  background: url("images/header.avif") center/cover;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40rem;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Comment: can you also add image depicting what you call "weird" behavior of image?

Answer (score 0):

apply `object-fit:cover` or `object-fit:stretch` property to image style

Comment: This question seems low quality, try posting an example code showing how to use this property.